# display notification django with ajax

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

I'm trying to show some data as notification click on the button the view will appear

```
class Post(models.Model):
     title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
     boolean = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

my views.py

```
from django.core import serializers
@login_required
def alerts(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        lists = Post.objects.filter(boolean=False)
        list_serializer = serializers.serialize('json',lists)
        return JsonResponse(list_serializer,safe=False)
    return JsonResponse({'message':'bad request'})
```

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.myBtn').click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url:'{% url 'posts:alerts' %}',
                type:'json',
                method:'GET',
                success:function(data){
                    var k;
                    for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                        k = '<div class="p-2 mt-1 text-center bgpurple textpurple">'
                        k+= '<p class="p-1 text-white border-2 bgpurple rounded-3xl">'+data[i]['title']+'</p>'
                        k+='</div>';

                    }
                    console.log(data)
                    document.getElementById('notification').innerHTML = k;
                }
            })
        })
    })
```

```html
        <div class="fixed z-50 w-1/5 h-screen overflow-y-scroll shadow-xl header" id="notification">
            <button class="px-4 py-1 m-2 bg-opacity-75 rounded-lg bgorange focus:outline-none myBtn" onclick="showNotifcation()"><i class="bi bi-x"></i></button>
            <!-- im trying to show the data here -->

        </div>
        
                <button class="relative px-6 py-1 rounded-full focus:outline-none textpurple" onclick="showNotifcation()" 
                    style="background-color: #ed9720;">
                        <span class="absolute top-0 w-4 h-4 text-xs rounded-full left-3 bgpurple" style="color: #ed9720;">display quantity of posts here</span>
                      <i class="fas fa-bell "></i>
                </button>
```

but it doesnt show anything except in the console return a dictionary
is there something i have to change or add please !

Comment: here `type:'json'` change to `dataType: "json"` . Also , show output of `data` as well .

Comment: out put of the data `[{"pk": 1, "fields": {"admin": 3, "title": "my first post", "boolean": true}},..` still not work , output of the html content is `undefined`